# Force lightbox to open in parent page php JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

Yet another newbie asking for help.

I have a Main_index.php page. Multiple divs are loaded into this page and each div has a "More" information button. Each div is a template style and is completed with mysql data.

```
<div class="more"><a href="advert_details.php?advert_id=<?php print $advert_id?>"id="more<?php print $advert_id?>"><?php echo MORE ?></a></div>
```

Each "More" button brings up a new page "advert_details.php", inside a lightbox. This is again a template style and loads details from mysql. The lightbox code is in the Main_index.php.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
        {
        $('a').filter(function() {
        return this.id.match(/more[0-9]/);
    }).fancybox({
        'overlayColor' : '#000',
        'overlayOpacity' : 0.1,
        'width' : 640,
        'height' : 940,
        'type' : 'iframe'
    });
});
</script>
```

If one of the "advert_details.php" pages is found by a search engine, when you click on the search result, the lightbox opens in a blank page.

Is there anything I can add, to force the "advert_details.php" page to open in the "main_index.php" page, making use of the lightbox JavaScript and showing the main site page?

I hope that I have explained this well, if not, please ask for more details.

Thanks

Peter

Answer (score 0):

You can set a URL parameter which will be checked to include the `advert_details.php` in the main page.

Something like

```
if(isset($_GET['showDetails'])) {
   include "advert_details.php";
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for your comment, but.The advert details page is not a problem when you are on the main_index page. The problem is when a link to (for example) advert_details.php?advert_id=170, this simply opens the advert_details page and the page is correct and complete. The problem is, I need to force the main_index page to open and then the advert_details.php to open as the lightbox.

Comment: I have added the following to main_index.php                       
[code] $_SESSION['fromsite']='yes' [/code]

And this to advert_details.php                                      

[code] if(isset($_SESSION['fromsite'])){
 echo 'is set';
 }else{
 header('Location: http://www.mysite.com/main_index.php') ;
 }
[/code]
When coming from the site I get "is set". When coming from google I am redirected to the main_index.php.

Can someone help me to call the advert_details page?

Comment: @user1434701, I can't understand what is it you are trying to do. How is coming from google different that browsing your site. And Why are you developing your website in such way?

Comment: Each advert description is a php file that opens in a lightbox. When these php files are found in a search engine, they open as a basic php page. I want these files to force the main_index.php to open and then show the details page in the lightbox.